# Print string of information from dataset using index

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, indexing

I am trying to code so that it will take the index of a dish, that was inputed by a user, in a dataset then print everything from that row that contains information about the dish. I am stumbling when it comes to getting the index to select the information from the data set

This is the code I have so far

```
import csv

myfile=open('indian_food.csv','r')

def read_dish(myfile):

    dish=input('What is the dish?\n')
    index=myfile.index(dish)
    for row in myfile:
        line_count=index
        print(f'\t{row['dish name']} is made of{row['ingredients']} and is a {row['diet']} dish. It takes {row['cook_time']} to cook. It is a {row['flavor_profile']} {row['course']} from the state of {row['state']}. Which is from the {row['region']} of India.')
```

and im pulling data from a data set that looks like this [data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3YjK7.png) (indian_foods.csv) and i need to get this as an example “Pithe is made of Rice flour, wheat
flour, and is a vegetarian dish. It takes 35 minutes to cook. It is a sweet
dessert from the state of Assam, which is the North East region of India.” which is basically combining all the information from one selected. I need to be able to do this for the row inputed by the user.

Comment: I see you are new to stack overflow. Welcome. We need you to post your code explicitly in the question, not as a picture or a link.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using pandas for this. It is tailored to work with tables (dataframes) of data like this. I had to replicate your dataset for a few examples because it was in picture form, so you should not have to use some of the code I have. If you can get your data into a dataframe, which there is plenty of online resources on how to do that, then this should work. There is a function in pandas called read_csv() which will probably do this in one line of code for you.

```
import pandas as pd


def read_dish(dataframe):
    dish=input('What is the dish?\n')
    row_index = (dataframe['dish name'] == dish).argmax()
    row = dataframe.iloc[row_index]
    print(f"{row['dish name']} is made of {row['ingredients']} and is a {row['diet']} dish. It takes {row['cook_time']} to cook. It is a {row['flavor_profile']} {row['course']} from the state of {row['state']}. Which is from the {row['region']} of India.")

    
# ---------- This code is only here to replicate your example ----------
data = [['dish name', 'ingredients', 'diet', 'cook_time', 'flavor_profile', 'course', 'state', 'region'],
       ['Balu shahi', 'Maida flour, yogurt, oil, sugar', 'vegetarian', 25, 'sweet', 'dessert', 'West Bengal', 'East'],
       ['Boondi', 'Gram flour, ghee, sugar', 'vegetarian', 30, 'sweet', 'dessert', 'Rajasthan', 'West'],
       ['Laddu', 'Gram flour, ghee, sugar', 'vegetarian', 40, 'sweet', 'dessert', -1, -1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
headers = df.iloc[0].values
df.columns = headers
df.drop(index=0, axis=0, inplace=True)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

print(df)
read_dish(df)
```

**Output**

```
What is the dish?
 Boondi
Boondi is made of Gram flour, ghee, sugar and is a vegetarian dish. It takes 30 to cook. It is a sweet dessert from the state of Rajasthan. Which is from the West of India.
```